# resource interrupted as script but transfered with MIME type text/plain;

Tags: angular, ionic2

i am trying to write an object that contains data to it, I used cordova-file plugin to do it

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from 'ionic-native';
declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-listing',
  templateUrl: 'listing.html'
})
export class ListingPage {


user-data - {name: "yoke",
             phone: "0000",
             country: "country",
             email: "email"
            }
    writefile(){

            var text = this.user_data;
            var fileSystem = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
            var path = fileSystem + "MY_Folder/";
            console.log("going to write object to a file");

            File.writeFile(path, "userData.txt", text, true)
                .then(function (success) {
                    // success
                    console.log("file writing success", success);
                }, function (error) {
                    // error
                    console.log("file writeing error", error);
                });
        }
create(){
        console.log("create");

        File.createFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory  , "Vanan/Van.txt", false)
                .then(function (success) {
                // success
                console.log("folder created", success);
                }, function (error) {
                // error
                    console.log("folder not created", error)
            });   

    }

}
```

I need to write the user-data object to a new text file. If i use .txt extension i get this error. My main target is to write some data to a file with what ever extension and i also need to read that file containing object and it should be stored to a persistent location

[image]

Comment: What of the `console.log(...)` are actually printed?

Comment: it goes to error block "MODIFICATION ERR" and "PATHEXIST ERR" if i check it with my file manager in android device i could not see any file created

Comment: "Actually it goes to err block". I'd expect it to print an error in this case.

Comment: What is the value of path you are getting in console?

Comment: i am geting this error  {code: 1, message: "NOT_FOUND_ERR"}  @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Perhaps you need to create the directory first (I don't know Ionic)